# Using GoDaddy email AND Google Apps

Tags: google, godaddy

We have 8 people that need emails addresses in our company. 3 need email only, while 5 need emails and the features from Google Apps. We would like to continue to host email for the 3 on GoDaddy, while using Google Apps for the 5. When we insert the MX records in GoDaddy, the 3 no longer could send/receive email, since we were redirecting email to Google.

How can we redirect email to these 3 employees through GoDaddy, while keeping the 5 on Google Apps?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach would be to setup Google apps on a [sub-domain](http://www.trunetservices.com/google-apps-sub-domain.html) like `marketing.yourdomain.com`. Spliting the departments into sub-domains would allow you to have multiple free standard edition accounts.

Alternatively you could buy another TLD like `yourdomain.net` and run apps from that leaving the existing setup in place.

Neither is really ideal though.

I don't see why you would setup only 5 accounts in apps when [Google Apps Standard Edition](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/standard/new3) is free for up to 10 users. You could set everyone up in apps and simply give the three who only need email access to Gmail and nothing else, it would save you the admin overhead and your staff the headache of having radically different email addresses.

Comment: We need the mail space as well as Google Video. I see that in the Google apps manager there is a section in settings > email for email rerouting. Is this usable.

Comment: @ThePants That makes sense. but the re-route would not help in a way that would solve your problem I'm afraid, you would need to move all the MX records to Apps which would leave you in the same boat you're in now - it would have to be a sub-domain, or new TLD to work for your situation.